# Statement is true or false

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading linear algebra & suddenly found this problem :

Let
$X = \{A = \left( a_{ij} \right) \in M_{22} (\mathbb{R}) \mid \operatorname{tr}(A) = 0$ and $|a_{ij}| \leq 2 \quad \forall 1 ≤ i,j ≤ 2\}$ and
let $Y = \{det(A) | A ∈ X\} ⊂ \mathbb R$.

Then, there exist $\alpha <0$ and $\beta > 0$ such
that $Y = [\alpha,\beta].$

The problem is whether the statement is true or false. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with *compactness* and *connectedness* then you simply need to show that $X$ is both compact and connected, and hence its continuous image (by $f(A)=\det A$), needs also to be a connected and compact subset of $\mathbb R$, and are only the closed intervals.

$X$ is compact. It is indeed bounded, as $\lvert a_{ij}\rvert\le 2$. It is also closed, since it is the the intersection 5 closed sets
$$
X_{ij}=\{A:\mathscr M_2(\mathbb R): \lvert a_{ij}\rvert\le 2\},\quad i,j=1,2, \quad X_5=\{A:\mathscr M_2(\mathbb R):\mathrm{Tr}(A)=0\}.
$$ 
$X_5$ is closed as the inverse of a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ via a continuous map, i.e., $X_5=\mathrm{Tr}^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Comment: will you please explain or provide some hints on how to show atleast one of the two@Yiorgos

Comment: I need the hints also on why is determinant map continuous.Please help sir

Comment: The determinant is a polynomial in the entries, and polynomials are continuous.